# phpunit- How to mock object with mokery in test case

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a `Contact` class. This class calls the `select` method of the `DB` class. It looks like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    $db= new DB;
    $data=$db->select();
    return (['data'=>$data']);
}
```

How can I mock data of the `select` method in my test case with Mockery of phpunit?

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: no, It is easy if it is Laravel

Answer (score 1):

If the `DB` you're using here is Laravel's DB facade you could use:

```
    DB::shouldReceive('select')
     ->andReturn([]);
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
    $dbMock = Mockery::mock('overload:DB');
    $dbMock->shouldReceive('select')->andReturn([]);
```

And put `use Mockery;` in the top of your test class.

Comment: i dont use laravel

Comment: The second example doesn't use Laravel.